# What is the proper syntax to exclude rows that have a specific ID, but lack a row in a related table with a value in a column on that row?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

Currently working on getting my head around the ordering of things, not even with laravel at first, but sql. Though the end goal is to use eloquent.

There are 2 conditions for the rows that need to be excluded. If I'm fetching the rows from TableA..

**1) TableA with the column status_id (or TableC.id) has to have lets say a value of 1.**

**2) TableB has to have an instance for that TableA.id where status_id (or TableC.id) is lets say 2.**

Been looking at whereNotIn, whereExists and when for a while now, but can't wrap my head around what is correct for the situation and how it should look like.

Still learning about sql queries and I am very grateful for any tips on this dilemma.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A raw SQL query for this might be:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a
WHERE status_id = 1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableB b WHERE b.a_id = a.id AND b.status_id = 2);
```

You never posted any Laravel/PHP code, so I'm not sure that attempting to give any code in Laravel would be that helpful.  You may base your Laravel code on the above query.